# Product of topological space pairs

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was reading Weintraub's Fundamentals of Algebraic Topology, and encountered a rather strange definition to me: the product of two pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ is $(X\times Y,X\times B\cup A\times Y)$. I don't know where does this $X\times B\cup A\times Y$ come from.

Comment: I do presume you know very well what a product of topological spaces is. Ok. And now you have a "definition" of "a pair". Presumably this definition is made with some purpose in mind. If we know that purpose, it would most likely explain the specific set-theoretic description of "product of a pair". In particular, for example, the product of $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ is not $(X\times Y,A\times B)$, though it's certainly easy enough, notationally, to write that. So, surely the best explanation is to think what "pair" is meant to accomplish, and what a "product" of two would accomplish.

Comment: Do you know some category theory?

Comment: @PaulFrost I do, I know there are product and coproduct, and they are special cases of limit and colimit.

Comment: Okay, then please add the context where the "product pair" appears. Künneth formula?

Answer (score 1):

In the category of pointed topological spaces, the universal property is $[(X\wedge Y,(x_0,y_0)),(Z,z_0)]=[(X,x_0),((Z,z_0)^{(Y,y_0)},\omega_0)]$ where $[X,Y]$ denotes the set of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$ while $Z^Y$ denotes the *space* of continuous maps from $Y$ to $Z$ (with the compact-open topology) and $\omega_0$ is the constant map. The first guy here is the smash product $X\wedge Y=X\times Y/(X\times y_0\cup x_0\times Y)$ which is much more analogous to the tensor product than the categorical product (this is essentially the tensor-hom adjunction, notice that maps between topological spaces themselves form a topological space similar to how homs themselves form a module!) I think that the general case where you're taking a pair relative to an arbitrary subset $A$ should be similar, but I don't quite know what $\omega_0$ would become. Perhaps it makes more sense to consider this as the smash product of $X/A$ and $Y/B$?

Comment: I think more generally, it should be $[(X\times Y,X\times B\cup A\times Y),(Z,C)]=[(X,A),((Z,C)^{(Y,B)},D)]$ where $D$ is the spaces of maps $Y\to Z$ whose image lies in $C$. Thus it is left adjoint to "homs" (space of continuous maps) which becomes a topological pair as described.